# jQuery: Adding Class to Paragraphs Not Working

Tags: jquery, class

I need to add a class to all my paragraphs (with the same class) - I will also be doing something similar for links as well. Anyhow, none of my paragraphs have IDs or classes from the getgo, as I need to declutter the html file as much as possible for others.

The issue I'm having is that I do not understand my error in my code. I have tested it, and it doesn't seem to working for some reason. Looks like it makes sense to me, but I guess I am missing something? (And yes, I am calling the jQuery library).

jQuery

```
$("#french").click(function(){
$("p").addClass("test_class");
});
```

And my html:

```
<div> 
<a href="#" id="french">Switch to French</a>
</div>


<div>
<div id="test_id" lang="en">Text test</div>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6u56yp06/ is that all your code?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've been modifying it and trying a few browsers. Is there something specific I might be missing that I think I am doing?

Comment: As @AndrewLi said, your code seems to be working as described. What are you asking? What is not working as you expect it to? What error are you seeing? Please be specific, "it's not working" is not a problem statement we can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew said, this looks good. The only thing I can think of is this: if you;re using some document ready prep, check that out to make sure there are no errors.  sometimes it possible that you could have erased  or added a char by accident.

Comment: Indeed, I had an error. I added an S. I must have hit the S key when trying to save. I feel dumb now :/, but I do appreciate that simple piece of answer.